# Local macro on subsample data using if statement in Stata

Tags: if-statement, dataset, stata

I want to use the `local` command in Stata to store several variables that I afterwards want to export as two subsamples. I separate the dataset by the grouping variable `grouping_var`, which is either 0 or 1. I tried:

```
if grouping_var==0 local vars_0 var1 var2 var3 var4
preserve
keep `vars_0'
saveold "data1", replace
restore

if grouping_var==1 local vars_1 var1 var2 var3 var4
preserve
keep `vars_1'
saveold "data2", replace
restore
```

However, the output is not as I expected and the data is not divided into two subsamples. The first list includes the whole dataset. Is there anything wrong in how I use the `if` statement here?

Comment: I guess you realise this but only the **names** of the variables are being stored in each local macro; not the variables themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bit of confusion between the "if qualifier" and the "if command" here. The syntax `if (condition) (command)` is the "if command", and generally does not provide the desired behavior when written using observation-level logical conditions.

In short, Stata evaluates `if (condition)` for the first observation, which is why your entire data set is being kept/saved in the first block (*i.e.*, in your current sort order, `grouping_var[1] == 0`). See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/ for more information.

Assuming you want to keep *different* variables in each case, something like the code below should work:

```
local vars_0 var1 var2 var3 var4
local vars_1 var5 var6 var7 var8
forvalues g = 0/1 {
    preserve
        keep if grouping_var == `g'
        keep `vars_`g''
        save data`g' , replace
    restore
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And if I want to have the same variables can I just replace the second line with var1 var2 var3 var4?

Comment: Something like `if frog[42] == 7` is perfectly legal and so observation-specific decisions are perfectly possible with the `if` command. It's just that that would be unusual to see in programs. What's important is that there is no tacit loop over the observations implied by the `if` command: every time it is invoked, there is just one decision.

Comment: @jeffrey: If you want to keep the same variables each time, there isn't really a need to define a local macro, unless you are using the same list of variables elsewhere. You could just write `keep var1 var2 var3 var4` inside the loop.

Comment: @NickCox: Good point, of course. I've edited the answer accordingly.